# Microsoft Security Essentials - Log indicates it keeps crashing

Tags: ms-security-essentials

I started up my PC/Windows 7 64-bit tonight and since then Microsoft Security Essentials (MSE) seems to keep crashing.  I uninstalled MSE then re-installed it, but still the same issue.  Each time MSE stops/crashes I try to restart it, but still crashes.

Here are some of the logs from the Event Viewer:

Windows Error Reporting

---

```
Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: APPCRASH
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: MsMpEng.exe
P2: 4.10.209.0
P3: 582a94a1
P4: mpengine.dll
P5: 1.1.15700.9
P6: 5c6dce74
P7: c0000005
P8: 0000000000391480
P9:
P10:

Attached files:

These files may be available here:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\AppCrash_MsMpEng.exe_62d24e52cbdd7e48bb9195fc7f67cdb398d769a4_27a20ab9

Analysis symbol:
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: dd6bbbb8-4a1b-11e9-b437-04d3b04a8c7d
Report Status: 4
```

Application Error  --------------------------------------------------------

```
Faulting application name: MsMpEng.exe, version: 4.10.209.0, time stamp: 0x582a94a1
Faulting module name: mpengine.dll, version: 1.1.15700.9, time stamp: 0x5c6dce74
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000391480
Faulting process id: 0x23cc
Faulting application start time: 0x01d4de283d068912
Faulting application path: c:\Program Files\Microsoft Security Client\MsMpEng.exe
Faulting module path: c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\Definition Updates\{EC7E7EBD-47CB-4269-8649-AA7A50387BBE}\mpengine.dll
Report Id: a636b137-4a1b-11e9-b437-04d3b04a8c7d
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this?  I used some info from these logs, but I haven't found anything as of yet.

Regards,

Mark

Comment: Seems this was a definitions issues based upon the discussions here: [1](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/18ab60a3-3b26-4a07-b68d-84085ce66ce5/scep-crashing-pcs) and [2](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/microsoft-antimalware-crashing-with-error-0x800106ba-on-windows-7-and-8/)

Answer (score 1):

Running

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Security Client\mpcmdrun.exe" -RemoveDefinitions
```

Provides temporary relief by rolling back the faulty definitions update.  I still haven't worked out how to prevent it promptly reinstalling them though!

Answer (score 1):

Had same situation here but Update Defs as of 21:00 - seems to have cured the issue

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please at least tell us what version those definitions are. Without that information this is not an answer.